# How to fire a cordova event without overriding?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

Example:

```js
document.addEventListener("volumeupbutton", onVolumeUpKeyDown, false);

function onVolumeUpKeyDown() {

    // This handler override the default «Volume Up» action
}
```

Specifically, my problem is on android.

I need do another action when the volume up button is pressed, and also increase the volume...

Comment: Can't test it right now, but maybe a call to `super.onVolumeUpKeyDown()` could help? Not sure it is even possible, but I know such calls are used for `gesture event handlers`.

Comment: have you tried? with back button, it executes back button default code and the code you put in your functions unless you use e.preventDefault();

Comment: That's a good idea, @Guillem, but I not realize how to execute the father's function: `this.__super__.whatFunction.apply(this, arguments)`?

Comment: Yes, @jcesarmobile, I tried and It doesn't execute the expected behavior :/ like with backbutton

Comment: I guess it's because just the backbutton is handled differently. Look at [this portion of the cordova-android code](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewImpl.java#L549)

Comment: @AlexisCaffa, the calls I have seen are similar to what i put on my first comment. Search for other events like `onClick`

Answer (score 2):

@AlexisCaffa,

you have two (2) paths

1. use a plugin. There are [two available](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=volume), only one works with Android.
2. use a different button.

[My notes on Phonegap events](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/Phonegap-Events-test) indicate that unless you use a plugin, the volume button is only available for the blackberry.

Best of Luck